# How to push back a job to the last of the queue in Laravel Beanstalk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, queue, beanstalkd

How can I push a job back into the queue.

I tired

```
$job->release()
```

but it is pushing back on to the queue so the next job in the queue is that same job, I want the job send back to the last of the queue,which executes last. How can I do that?

Comment: Delete the job and push it back as a new job.

Comment: Is there any other solution like $job->release() ?

Comment: There is a priority parameter that can be used for release, but Laravel's job [`release`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/BeanstalkdJob.php#L84-L91) method doesn't offer any way for it to be passed. It just uses the default priority constant `Pheanstalk::DEFAULT_PRIORITY` it gets from [Pheanstalk](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk) (the package it uses to handle Benastalk queues). So if you want to be able to handle more specific properties of the queues you should use Pheanstalk instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception making the job fail.

And depending on how many tries the queue:work will fire, the job will ultimately end up in the failed_jobs table (if you have that defined.)

You can then push the job back on to the queue from the failed_jobs table.